# Hide / show with *ngIf Angular2

Tags: angular, event-binding, angular-ng-if

I have two elements which I want to hide and show based on `*ngIf` condition value.

By default my `wrap` block is visible and when I click on one of its `divs` this `wrap`block should disappear and only the chosen `div's` content should be displayed inside my `span` element.
Then when I click on my `span` element it should disappear and `wrap` block should come again with all its default content.

To implement that I use `*ngIf` with value `visability` for both elements, expecting that my functions work in following way:

```
wrap - visible;
span - hidden;

wrap - hidden;
span - visible;
```

Here's my code:

```
@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `
<div id="wrap" class="wrap" *ngIf="visability">
<div (click)="clicked($event)">
  <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
</div>
<div (click)="clicked($event)">
  <h2>Hello {{year}}</h2>
</div>
<div (click)="clicked($event)">
  <h2>Hello {{surname}}</h2>
</div>
<div (click)="clicked($event)">
  <h2>Hello {{country}}</h2>
</div>
<div (click)="clicked($event)">
  <h2>Hello {{cartoon}}</h2>
</div>
```

```
 <div class="view">
  <span id="span" (click)="showDivs()" *ngIf="visability">{{target}}    </span>
 </div>

 `,
})
export class App {
name:string;
year: string;
surname: string;
country: string;
cartoon: string;
element: any;
target: any;

constructor() {
var wrap = document.getElementById("wrap");
var span = document.getElementById("span");
this.name = 'Angular2'
 this.year = '1989'
  this.surname = 'Connor'
   this.country = 'USA'
    this.cartoon = 'Tom & Jerry'
  }

clicked(event) {
wrap.visability = false;
span.visability = true;
this.target = event.target.innerText;
} 

showDivs(){
span.visability = false;
wrap.visability = true;
}

}
```

[My Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/yWsDkYdqIStkLX7yKMFB?p=preview)

Why my functions don't work in a proper way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually changed your code a bit. Put `visability` as true for the first div, and false for the second. To separate them better. Then it's just to toggle the booleans based on click, like so:

First declare the visability as a variable so that you can refer to it with `this` then just toggle the visability.

```
  clicked(event) {
    this.visability = false;
    this.target = event.target.innerText;
  }
```

and

```
  showDivs(){
    this.visability = true;
    // span.visability = false; // remove this
    // wrap.visability = true;  // remove this
  }
```

and the html accordingly:

```
<div id="wrap" class="wrap" *ngIf="visability">
```

and

```
<span id="span" (click)="showDivs()" *ngIf="!visability">{{target}}</span>
```

This is one solution.

### Your [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/FsrJZPIrzogud5PsRP0t?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by removing `*ngIf` for my second element. I just used *ngIf="shown" for the `span`.

Then in constructor I set both

```
visibility = true
```

and

```
shown = true
```

Inside the functions I switched the values to opposite, thus managed to achieve what I wanted, though I don't know if it's the best way to go.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <div id="wrap" class="wrap" *ngIf="visibility">
    <div (click)="clicked($event)">
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
    <div (click)="clicked($event)">
      <h2>Hello {{year}}</h2>
    </div>
    <div (click)="clicked($event)">
      <h2>Hello {{surname}}</h2>
    </div>
    <div (click)="clicked($event)">
      <h2>Hello {{country}}</h2>
    </div>
    <div (click)="clicked($event)">
      <h2>Hello {{cartoon}}</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="view">
    <span id="span" (click)="showDivs()" *ngIf="shown">{{target}}</span>
  </div>

  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  year: string;
  surname: string;
  country: string;
  cartoon: string;
  element: any;
  target: any;

  clicked(event) {
     this.target = event.target.innerText;
     this.visibility = false;
     this.shown = true;
  }

  showDivs(){
     this.shown = false;
     this.visibility = true;
  }

  constructor() {
    this.visibility = true;
    this.shown = true;
    this.name = 'Angular2'
     this.year = '1989'
      this.surname = 'Connor'
       this.country = 'USA'
        this.cartoon = 'Tom & Jerry'
  }



}
```

[Working Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/69SrI57vcM3lincBnKF1?p=preview)